# How to access all of oData in stackoverflow data explorer?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

I want to get all the Tags from the data explorer (http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/query/new) but my query results get truncated to 2000 records. How can I get the whole thing?

Thanks!

Comment: The row limit is now 50000

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it return more than 2000 rows, it's a hard limit to stop queries from overloading the system. You *can* do piecemeal queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE Id < 2000;
SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE Id >= 2000 AND Id < 4000;​
-- etc.
```

but that would take a while (we're on id 29239 right now). It's probably easier to download [the latest data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/creative-commons-data-dump-aug-10/) yourself so you can load up the whole database and operate on it locally

Comment: The row limit is now 50000

Answer (score 2):

There are almost 30,000 tags in the Stack Overflow data set, but the Data Explorer is limited to returning 2,000 results at a time.

**EDIT:** Here is the best solution. Output the results of this to text so you can copy/paste. This generates the entire set of tags as an XML document, which you can parse:

```
    SELECT TagName AS Name FROM Tags FOR XML RAW('Tag'), ROOT('Tags')
```

---

Since you're free to use any SQL you want, there are a bunch of ways of doing this, not all of which work.

1. Write a query to return a specific 2,000 records in each query, and run it 15 times (basis of a query is shown in Michael's answer)
2. Write a query that concatenates the data you want into a string, run that, and process the results yourself. This query times out for some reason. (I used a `WITH` because I was testing `TOP n`.)

   ```
   DECLARE @results nvarchar(MAX)
   WITH c AS
   (
       SELECT TagName FROM Tags
   )
   SELECT @results = COALESCE(@results + ',', N'') + TagName FROM c
   SELECT @results
   ```
3. Get tricky (this actually works, though the tags are not in alpha order -- I assume you can take care of that later).

   ```
   SELECT
       t1.TagName, t2.TagName, t3.TagName, t4.TagName, t5.TagName,
       t6.TagName, t7.TagName, t8.TagName, t9.TagName, t10.TagName,
       t11.TagName, t12.TagName, t13.TagName, t14.TagName, t15.TagName
       FROM
           Tags t1
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t3 ON t3.Id = t2.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t4 ON t4.Id = t3.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t5 ON t5.Id = t4.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t6 ON t6.Id = t5.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t7 ON t7.Id = t6.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t8 ON t8.Id = t7.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t9 ON t9.Id = t8.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t10 ON t10.Id = t9.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t11 ON t11.Id = t10.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t12 ON t12.Id = t11.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t13 ON t13.Id = t12.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t14 ON t14.Id = t13.Id + 2000
           LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags t15 ON t15.Id = t14.Id + 2000
       WHERE t1.Id <= 2000
   ```

Comment: Lol, #3 is funny. I would of never thought of doing something like that

Comment: The row limit is now 50000

Answer (score 0):

Its truncated to 2000 rows due to performance and to prevent possible abuse. To get everything requires using the full data dump in XML or using another database port

Comment: The row limit is now 50000