# Any way to get full result set from the data explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access all of oData in stackoverflow data explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62573/how-to-access-all-of-odata-in-stackoverflow-data-explorer)

Seems my query results in the data explorer have an automatic limit of 50,000 results (I did a query on all Users, and only got 50,000 results back). Is there any way to get the full result set?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to access all of oData in stackoverflow data explorer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62573/how-to-access-all-of-odata-in-stackoverflow-data-explorer)

Comment: @CodyGray, that solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: (I'd even say this is a duplicate question really -- any easy way to mark it as such without community involvement? or should I just delete this question since it's already covered?)

Comment: Eh, I'd leave it and let it get closed by the community. I think yours is much more searchable (findable?).

Comment: Did you have a specific use case for this, by the way?

Comment: @TimStone, I had one but realized I could accomplish the same thing with a much simpler query (with less returned data) in the data explorer. I still decided to download the whole data set yesterday and I'm going to play around with it in the next few days.